# Timed out receiving message from renderer error

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Recently, while running the automation test, specifically the long tests (Regression), the test just stuck and I am getting an error in the console (Autorun) that says:

> Timed out receiving message from renderer: 30.000

Versions:

- Chrome version: 94.0.4606.81
- Chrome driver version: 94.0.4606.6100
- Selenium web driver version: 3.141.0

Chrome driver options:

```
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-web-security");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu"); //may fix some errors that can be created with google GPU
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--allow-running-insecure-content");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("window-size=1920,1080");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("force-device-scale-factor=0.75");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("high-dpi-support=0.75");
        return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Does this happen randomly? Is it one specific piece of code in your test suite that does this?

Comment: No, it happens after some amount of time, on long tests actually (Regression). @GregBurghardt

Comment: Does the test itself run a long time, or does the test run (all the tests combined) run a long time? I've had problems like this with a single test that takes a long time. Depending on how the test is written, it might be good to kill and restart ChromeDriver periodically if you can essentially pause the test and start it back up from where you left off.